# Interfacing a mobile phone with php

Tags: php, mobile, sms

*dont really know if the title is apt but believe you will understand after reading*

i am presently working on a project and am stuck.

I have a mobile phone connected to a computer, i want to be able to access text messages immediately they come into the mobile phone from the computer.

The project i am doing is php based, please how can i go about it?

Comment: What kind of mobile phone are we talking about?

Comment: That is an **incredibly** open question! What are you stuck on what have you done so far, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to reverse engineer the protocols used by the phone's manufacturer to interface between the phone and the manufacturer's desktop software. Basically a difficult task. Thankfully there's lots of cell enthusiasts who've done this already for many makes. Look at the [BitPim](http://www.bitpim.org/) project for some guidance - it's GPL'd so you can pick at the source and see how they accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXperts SMS Messaging Server http://www.activexperts.com/mmserver/, it is a windows service and uses database, you can attach a compatible mobile phone or gsm module.
You just have to write message in its database it will automatically send it and you can read a received message as well from database.
Super easy to use, i recommend it because i have used it in one of my project.